# Is "fierceless" a word, and if so, what is its etymology?

Tags: meaning, etymology

From a Safire NYT column:

> Nobody intimidated him back, not the Government, whose I.R.S. he challenged; not the Mafia, some of whose hoods he defended; not the press, whose bad publicity he courted; not the Catholic Church whose Archdiocese in New York he represented; not ''bomber'' lawyers, whom he out-bombed in court; not even Frank Sinatra, whom he was willing to offend when I needed on-the-record verification for a story in this space. How many other ***fierceless*** advocates can you name?" {emphasis added} (NYT, 1986-08-04, https://www.nytimes.com/1986/08/04/opinion/essay-about-roy-cohn.html)

Obviously, Safire cared deeply about language.  I assume this was an intentional usage of an obscure word or alternate spelling, but it is new to me and not readily found on the Web.  I hope future searchers will find an answer here.

Comment: I suspect it's a typo for "fearless." "Not fierce" wouldn't make sense in context.

Comment: There are a few usages from Google Books https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fierceless%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1914,cd_max:1985&lr=lang_en

Comment: Either a quirky non-standardism or a typo.

Comment: @alphabet he probably was fearless, but if he had been fierce he likely *would* have had a strong reaction from the parties mentioned. Perhaps his technique was a calm, unarguable presentation of facts. But... OTOH the linked NYT story says "he was brilliant, professionally intimidating, iconoclastic".

Comment: If *Nobody intimidated him*, he was fierce. Not less than others, more than most. I vote to go back to 1986 and correct that Safire. Fearless. Done.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a common word as far as I know, and its literal interpretation doesn't make much sense. The "-less" suffix is normally appended to a noun, creating an adjective that means lacking the quality that the noun represents (e.g. "fearless" means "having no fear"). But "fierce" is an adjective, not a noun, so it doesn't accept the "-less" suffix.

It's not in the OED. But [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fierceless%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1914,cd_max:1985&lr=lang_en) has examples as far back as the early 19th century. It seems to be a portmanteau of "fierce" and "fearless".